# Options to speed up Hobbyist Rendering?

Tags: software, linux, animation-rendering, blender

How can I speed up hobbyist animation-rendering project? It would be cool to see things faster, I use tools such as Blender.

Comment: Better CPUs? You could be more specific on what kind of stuff you actually want to render, but for the tasks they can do at all GPUs are obviously more effective.

Comment: You have some links to Blender related stuff, but you don't actually say anything about what you are rendering.  It's impossible to offer any advice without any specifics whatsoever.  What's slowing you down?

Comment: another idea -- export in the same format as the source material (in final cut), which will skip rendering/re-encoding. See: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26174?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

- Turning off ray tracing
- Lowering the resolution
- Turning off soft shadows unless needed
- In Blender, use the Simplify option

These and others are covered in [this blenderguru article](http://www.blenderguru.com/13-ways-to-reduce-render-times)

Answer (score 1):

**Some novel ideas**

> 1. physical: better CPUs, more RAM
> 2. crowdsourcing: render farms & distributed rendering like [here](http://www.renderfarm.fi/blog/prodigalson/first-cycles-render-ever-renderfarmfi)
> 3. knowledge & experience: elegant simple shortcuts -- keep things simple: no smoke or fluid etc CPU-expensive stuff

**Perhaps Related, found after some googling but not sure**

> 1. http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-246/distributed-rendering-new-render-options/
> 2. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?86521-How-do-you-set-up-a-render-farm
> 3. http://burp.renderfarming.net/
> 4. http://www.respower.com/

Comment: Renderfarm.fi is reworking their website, the first linked blog post isn't yet migrated to the new platform. Please link to main page http://www.renderfarm.fi instead.